# form - enable middle click on submit button (using pure html only!)

Tags: html

I have 4 links. Previously implemented as A tags.
My goal is to switch the request method (GET) with POST. Everything else have to remain the same!

The problem - it must be implemented using pure HTML - to be exact - no ajax and no window.open(). 
My solution is half way there. Hopefully to get a creative second half from you (impossible is also an answer)

Here is the (simplified) HTML:

```
<form
            id = "resultsForm"
            target="_blank"
            action="http://example.com"
            method="post"

    >
        <input type="hidden" name="data" value="someData">
        <button  type="submit" value="submit">
            <p class="contextual"> title </p>
            <span></span>
        </button>
</form>
```

Now, it looks and feels like the old implementation and also sends POST requests

But - contrary to a link - a button can't be middle clicked or opened in new window when right clicking on it (by default...) 
Can I somehow wrap it in an A tag to achieve the explained behavior without using js events or be conflicted with form subbmission?

Your help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is impossible.

- Anchor elements cannot contain interactive elements such as `button` elements.
- Forms should be posted to the `target` window, so a normal click on the submit button, by virtue of the `_blank` value, should open an unnamed browsing context (a new window or tab).

Users should be accustomed to not middle-clicking on buttons, although there is a habit of developers to style links to look like buttons, throwing off users' expectations (end rant:)).